# google-services.json integration for non-standart android project structure

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, linphone, google-play-services

I know that **google-services.json** must be inside the **app** directory, my problem is that I don't have this folder, my project folders structure is messy. How can I fix this problem? where I should insert this file? Or if it possible to transform this structure to the default standart android project?, inside this project there is only one **build.gradle** file

this is error log

```
    Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
    file:/opt/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
Required by:
    :linphone-android (copy):unspecified
```

build.gradle

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
}
```

and at the bottom

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my project structure
[image]
[image]

Comment: you have to insert that file in app folder of your project directly not from android studio. and please provide some more detail and screens of your structure. google-services.json cant be visible in structure but it is there in your project folder

Comment: Yes I know that. and I don't have this folder

Comment: show your project structure please. Post image of your structure

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Please change above spinner which shows in screenshot from project to Android and send screenshot.

Comment: please check it again

Comment: your src and google-services.json are in same folder please check?

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: So where is the problem? when you getting problem? and which problem is occurs? if there is any error post your logcat

Comment: I added the error log

Comment: you are using this for firebase right? So which firebase dependencies you added?

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2' try adding this two dependencies

Comment: nope there is same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is resolved on this commit:
https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/commit/da76f636ceb06daf28bc4d98db8faa044b90cbee

We just add a check if 'google-services.json' exist or not and add dependencies according with this.

Answer (score 0):

plz try to put where app grade file is there means  gradle and json file shold be there go to folder direcly and past don't use android studio for  paste that file. where android studio can read gradle it can also read json from there

Comment: Yes service json and build.gradle are in same directory, but same problem

Comment: do 1 think put every main of common   folder of your project where you can put just gradel if successfull then delete one by one and  check